# Inserindo e atualizando dados em tabelas N-N (muitos para muitos)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou com problema em salvar em um relacionamento de muitos para muitos, segue meu modelo:

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Conta> Conta { get; set; }
}


public class Conta
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string descricao { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoa { get; set; }
}
```

Aqui está a configuração no meu contexto para n-n:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Pessoa>()
        .HasMany<Conta>(x => x.Conta)
        .WithMany(x => x.Pessa)
        .Map(x =>
        {
            x.ToTable("PessoaConta");
            x.MapLeftKey("pessoaId");
            x.MapRightKey("contaId");
        });
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Até aqui tudo bem: meu esquema de *migrations* funciona perfeitamente, mas gostaria de saber quando salvar os dados na tabela `pessoa` e tabela `conta` já inserir os valores respectivos na tabela `pessoaConta`. Desde já agradeço a todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As *Collections* precisam ser `virtual`. Procure também usar nomes no plural:

```
public virtual ICollection<Conta> Contas { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> Pessoas { get; set; }
```

Faça alguns testes:

```
var fulano = new Pessoa { descricao = "Fulano" };
var beltrano = new Pessoa { descricao = "Beltrano" };
var sicrano = new Pessoa { descricao = "Sicrano" };

context.Pessoas.Add(fulano);
context.Pessoas.Add(beltrano);
context.Pessoas.Add(sicrano);

context.SaveChanges();

var conta = new Conta { descricao = "Conta Coletiva" };
conta.Pessoas = new List<Pessoa> { fulano, beltrano, sicrano };
context.Contas.Add(conta);

context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: resolveu temporariamente, mas apareceu o seguinte problema. seria possível quando já tiver a conta e a pessoa registrada fazer a vinculação dos dados na tabela N-N

Comment: Aí você tem que mapear manual. [Veja mais aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+associativa).